# Applying a function to a set rather than a value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, notation

I do apologize about the title, I dont understand the question so I couldnt come up with a better title, if someone else could edit it to a more meaningful title I would appreciate it.

So here is the question:

> Let $f(x) = \lfloor x^2/3 \rfloor$ and let $g(x) = x^2$
>
> 1. Find $f(S)$ if $S = \{1, −2, −1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$.
> 2. find $f^{-1}([-1/2, 3])$.
> 3. Find $(g \circ f)(S)$.

The confusing part is the fact that the set $S$ has many values; will $f(S)$'s result be in the form of a set? I am familiar with $f()$, $f^{-1}$ and $(g\circ f)(S)$ so please just explain what I need to do different when the input is a set of values rather than a single value.

Comment: Note that I changed $f\circ g(S)$ to $(f\circ g)(S)$ for the sake of "defensive parenthesization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation you (well, your text/teacher/whatever) are using is somewhat ambiguous, unfortunately.

I'll show you a different (but similar) notation that is less so:

If $f\colon A \to B$ is a function and $S\subset A$, then
$$f[S] = \{ y \in B \mid (\exists x \in S)(y=f(x)) \}.$$
$f[S]$ is called the *image* of $S$ *under* $f$.

The notation you're using uses $f(S)$ to mean $f[S]$. This works out fine in many contexts, but if you're mucking about with set theory, it can be horribly confusing.

As aschepler [notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602335/applying-a-function-to-a-set-rather-than-a-value/602352#comment1268752_602340), the notation $f^{-1}(T)$ (or, better, $f^{-1}[T]$), does *not* generally mean the image of $T$ under the inverse function of $f$, because $f$ may not have an inverse function. Rather, $f^{-1}[T]$ is the *inverse image* of $T$ under $f$, defined as
$$f^{-1}[T] = \{ a \in A \mid f(a) \in T \}.$$

Can you show that if $f$ in fact *does* have an inverse function then the inverse image of a set under $f$ is the same as the image of that set under $f^{-1}$?

P.S.

Yet another notation for the image of $S$ under $f\colon A \to B$ is $f''(S)$, where $f''$ is the "induced" function from $\mathcal P(A)$ to $\mathcal P(B)$. I would not recommend using this alternative outside the realm of set theory.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the post and leaving a detailed answer... so for the first part, I will just put each element in set `S` into the function and write the results as a set with 7 elements yea? and for part 2 I am not sure if I understood you correctly, what do you mean by `Rather, f−1[T] is the inverse image of T under f`? and as for the third part, `(f∘g)(S)` is it the same thing as part one? just input the numbers into from set `S` and produce the results as a set? again thanks a lot

Comment: The inverse image of $T$ under $f$ is the set of all points that $f$ maps into $T$. So if $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f(x) = x^2$, then $f^{-1}[\{4,9\}] = \{2,-2,3,-3\}$ whereas $f^{-1}[\{-3\}]=\varnothing$. I'm not sure what you're asking about the composition.

Comment: gotcha, thanks a lot man... and was I right about the other 2 questions?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi, I think so, yeah. Side note: if you are familiar with the idea of a function as a *relation* (a set of ordered pairs), you can rewrite the definitions of image and inverse image for general relations, which makes them much more symmetrical. I just didn't want to drag in another layer you might not know about yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $f(S)$ will be a set. It is defined as the set of all $y$ such that $y=f(s)$ where $s \in S$.
Same for any other operation, such as $f^{-1}(T)$ where $T$ is a set: this will be a set as well.

Comment: And when $T$ is a set, the notation $f^{-1}(T)$ has meaning even if the function is not invertible (like $f$ in the OP example).